TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'date_format'
I am getting this error:

TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'date_format'

While running the script I got this error. I am using MacBook Pro, Apple M1 Pro Chip, Mac OS Sonoma Version 14.5. Here is the script:
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, tzinfo,date,time
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import seaborn as sns
#%matplotlib inline
InfileT = "Users\\ramanujadasan\\Data\\Telemetry\\RFValidation\\Telemetry.csv"
InfileM = "Users\\ramanujadasan\\Data\\Telemetry\\RFValidation\\Manual.csv"

Tdata = pd.read_csv(InfileT,header = 0,index_col=0,parse_dates=['Date And Time (UTC)'],        date_format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S") 
Mdata = pd.read_csv(InfileM,header = 0,index_col=0,parse_dates=['Date And Time (UTC)'], date_format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
#Tdata = Tdata.resample('D').sum()
Tdata = Tdata.resample(rule='24H', closed='left', label='left', offset='8H').sum()
Mdata = Mdata.resample(rule='24H', closed='left', label='left', offset='8H').sum()
print (Tdata.head())
print (Mdata.head())

print (" Manual Data Available from ", Mdata.index[0]," to ",Mdata.index[-1])
print ("\n Telemetry Data Available from ", Tdata.index[0]," to ",Tdata.index[-1])
print ("\n Default settings for Whole period above. \n If selected period requried set value of mode variable to 2 (default value mode =1) and \n Modify the start and End date time in script ")
# mode  Full time period  = 1 , Selected Time period = 2
mode = 1
print ("Selected mode is "+str(mode))
if(mode == 2):
    # Algo for selected period
    sd = date(2021,5,1)
    st = time(2,30,0)
    start_date = datetime.combine(sd,st)
    ed = date(2021,5,31)
    et = time(2,30,0)
    end_date = datetime.combine(ed,et)
    Tdata = Tdata.loc[start_date:end_date]
    Mdata = Mdata.loc[start_date:end_date]
    # End Algo for selected period

# checking if Telemetry or Manual has earlier value

Combdata = pd.concat([Tdata, Mdata], axis=0, ignore_index=False)
Combdata['col'] = (len(Tdata)*(0,) + len(Mdata)*(1,))
Combdata['Type'] = ["Manual" if x == 1 else "Telemetry" for x in Combdata['col']]
Combdata['color'] = ["G" if x == 1 else "R" for x in Combdata['col']]
Combdata.reset_index(inplace=True)
Combdata['MonYear'] = Combdata['Date And Time (UTC)'].dt.strftime('%B %Y')
Combdata['Date'] = Combdata['Date And Time (UTC)'].dt.strftime('%d')
sitename = list(Tdata)
Tot_stns = len(sitename)
for i in range (0,Tot_stns):
    site  = sitename[i]
    print (site)
    sns.set(font_scale=1)
    fig = sns.catplot(data=Combdata.reset_index(),x = 'Date',y = site, hue='Type',kind ='bar', height = 10,aspect = 1,dodge = True,ci= None)
    fig.fig.suptitle("Comparision of Telemetry and Manual Rainfall Data at \n" +site+ " for " +Combdata['MonYear'][i], fontsize=15, y = 1.1)
    #fig.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.daylocator(interval=2))   #to get a tick every 15 minutes
    #fig.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d:%m'))     #optional formatting 
    fig.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)
    #plt.title("Comparision of Telemetry and Manual Rainfall Data at \n" +site, fontsize=12)
    #plt.figure(figsize(8,4))
    #plt.show(fig)
    #fig.suptitle('Comparision of Telemetry and Manual Rainfall Data at'+ '\n' +site, fontsize=12)
    fig.savefig('Users\\ramanujadasan\\Data\\Telemetry\\RFValidation\\'+site+".pdf")

How can I fix it?
